# How can I write the following Java code better?

Tags: java, input, for-loop

I have tried the following code in many ways but it just doesn't work. I have two problems with it.

1. I need it to not continue to QUANTITY when I press X.
2. If I want to continue, i.e., I do not press X but enter a code I should be pressing, it takes the first input correctly, however, when it goes around the loop the second type, it outputs something like "CODE: QUANTITY: " on the same line.

I would really appreciate help here, because I am stuck and google's been no help. I am completely new to programming, with no previous experience in any language, so I would really appreciate detailed help.

Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class WHY
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
          boolean count = true;

          for (int i = 0; count; i++)
          {
               System.out.print("CODE: (X to terminate)");
               String code = in.nextLine();
               System.out.print("QUANTITY: ");
               int quantity = in.nextInt();

               if (code.equals("X"))
                    count = false;
          }
     }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("CODE: (X to terminate)");
        String code = in.nextLine();
        if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.print("QUANTITY: ");
        int quantity = in.nextInt();
        in.nextLine();
    }
```

Comment: @Bohemian Thanks! I just forget it! I edited answer. +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample, procedural, pseudocode on how to simplify your statement (arrange it to fit in your class).

```
private static final String QUIT = "X";
String code = ""

while (!(code = readCode()).equalsIgnoreCase(QUIT)) {
    //Process the code read....
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("QUANTITY: ");
    int quantity = in.nextInt();
}

public String readCode() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("CODE: (X to terminate)");
    return in.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: did you leave out a `!` somewhere? and what exactly does `.equalsIgnoreCase()` do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println()`. This will create a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to break the loop as soon as the user enters 'X', you can use the `break` keyword to stop the loop. I also recommend replacing your `for` loop with a `while(true)` loop. This will keep looping for ever (and this is where the break keyword is used to stop it from looping indefinitely). `System.out.print` prints text in the same line, use `System.out.println()` to print text and move to the next line. Lastly, you should move your conditional statement just after you read the `code` value and replace `count = false` with `break`.

As a final tip, I would recommend you use the braces whenever you have an `if else` statement. This can help solve problem later on in development when you need to add an extra statement and forget about the braces or are too tired to notice ;).

Answer (score 0):

- Use while loop for boolean conditions, expecially if you don't use index anywhere. Use for loop for iterating elements of sequences.
- Use break statement to exit loop instead of using boolean condition **
- Use java coding style
- Use System.out.println output a line of text.

So basically:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class WHY {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(true) {
           System.out.print("CODE: (X to terminate)");
           String code = in.nextLine();
           System.out.println("QUANTITY: ");
           int quantity = in.nextInt();

           if (code.equals("X"))
                break;
        }
    }    
}
```

** matter of taste

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int total = 0;
while (true) {
    System.out.print("CODE: (X to terminate)");
    String code = in.nextLine();
    if (code.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.print("QUANTITY: ");
    int quantity = in.nextInt();
    total += quantity;
}
System.out.print("The total is: " + total);
```